# Download Virtual Device with Google Apps in GenyMotion

Tags: android, genymotion

How to Download Virtual Device with Google Apps in GenyMotion?,As of now my Wizard looks like this,But Instead of showing like this,I need "**Virtual Device with Google App - (eg :- Custom Phone-4.1.1 With Google App -API 16-768X1280)**"

[image]

Comment: You can manually add gapps to your VM

Answer (score 0):

1) Download the ARM Translation Installer v1.1(ARMTI)

2) Download the Google Apps for your Android version 4.4, 4.3, 4.2, or 4.1 for instance

3) Drag and drop the ARMTI to the HomeScreen of your emulator, and confirm all

4) Reboot your emulator

5) Drag & Drop the correct Google App version to your HomeScreen

6) Reboot your emulator

7) JOB DONE.